# Unexplained Cookies: style name location appearing for no reason

Tags: cookies

I have been noticing when debugging that I'm seeing 3 additional Cookies on my testing Windows XP PC that I don't see in Safari on the same PC or on my Mac or indeed other PCs. I created a simple PHP page with only:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
Development Only: Your current $_COOKIE contents are: <pre><?php print_r($_COOKIE); ?></pre>
```

When I view that on my test server I see the PHP info as normal then at the bottom I also get:

Development Only: Your current $_COOKIE contents are: 
Array
(
    [style] => default
    [name] => Steve Kemp
    [location] => Bondi, NSW
)

I can't see where these cookies are coming from as they only appear on one PC using Internet Explorer 8 at the moment. IE8 on other PCs doesn't show them. Does anyone know where the style, name and location cookies are being set and why only visible on one PC?

Many thanks,
Steve

Comment: Have you set them before for `localhost` ?

Comment: Thanks I managed to track it down to a cookie that had been set for the test server with those values. Not sure where it came from - seems pretty harmless though.

Comment: #Steve Kemp I added an answer, vote it up if you like :P

Answer (score 0):

Have you set cookies for `localhost` sometime in the past?